# I want output like to print the whole line which is having specific word and in which table it is present

Tags: text-processing

eg:

```
CREATE TABLE SSS.ACTIVITY ( 
 OWNING_ID INTEGER NOT NULL , 
ACTIVITY_TYPE FOR COLUMN ACTIV00001 VARCHAR(50) CCSID 37 NOT NULL , 
CAMPAIGN_TYPE FOR COLUMN CAMPA00001 VARCHAR(50) CCSID 37 NOT NULL , 
COMPLETED TIMESTAMP NOT NULL ,                                             "COMMENT" VARCHAR(1000) CCSID 37 DEFAULT NULL , 
 FOLLOWUP_DATE FOR COLUMN FOLLO00001 DATE DEFAULT NULL ,  
; 

CREATE TABLE SSS.ADDRESS ( 
"ID" INTEGER NOT NULL , 
 CITY VARCHAR(30) CCSID 37 DEFAULT NULL , 
COUNTRY VARCHAR(30) CCSID 37 DEFAULT NULL , 
ADDRESSLINE1 FOR COLUMN ADDRE00001 VARCHAR(30) CCSID 37 DEFAULT NULL , 
ADDRESSLINE2 FOR COLUMN ADDRE00002 VARCHAR(30) CCSID 37 DEFAULT NULL , 
;
```

In the above example two table is there. I need output like print the table name along with the line which is having CCSID word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing this with [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) :

```
$ awk '$1=="CREATE" && $2="TABLE"{table=$3} /CCSID/ && \
    table{print "table " table, ":", $0}' l
```

#### Output:

```
table SSS.ACTIVITY : ACTIVITY_TYPE FOR COLUMN ACTIV00001 VARCHAR(50) CCSID 37 NOT NULL , 
table SSS.ACTIVITY : CAMPAIGN_TYPE FOR COLUMN CAMPA00001 VARCHAR(50) CCSID 37 NOT NULL , 
table SSS.ACTIVITY : COMPLETED TIMESTAMP NOT NULL ,                                             "COMMENT" VARCHAR(1000) CCSID 37 DEFAULT NULL , 
table SSS.ADDRESS :  CITY VARCHAR(30) CCSID 37 DEFAULT NULL , 
table SSS.ADDRESS : COUNTRY VARCHAR(30) CCSID 37 DEFAULT NULL , 
table SSS.ADDRESS : ADDRESSLINE1 FOR COLUMN ADDRE00001 VARCHAR(30) CCSID 37 DEFAULT NULL , 
table SSS.ADDRESS : ADDRESSLINE2 FOR COLUMN ADDRE00002 VARCHAR(30) CCSID 37 DEFAULT NULL ,
```